# Twitter Direct Message Link - Convert <button> into <a>

Tags: javascript, twitter, converters, href

If you log into twitter, and Direct Message is enabled, you'll see a "Send Message" button appear. I desire that URL. How do I get the URL for sending a specific user a DM? I dug into the code, and this is what we have. Thoughts?

Thanks in advance for your attention buddy.

This is what the button looks like:

[image]

Here is the (trimmed) code if you (R) Click > Inspect

```
`<button type="button" data-name="XYZABCTwitterName" data-screen-name="xyzabctwittername" data-user-id="4203234760" data-original-title="Send a Direct Message to XYZABCTwitterName">
  <span>
    <span>Message</span>
  </span>
</button>`
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a setup flow here that walks you through it

https://publish.twitter.com/

It generates the a HTML link and script tag to activate it.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/messages/compose?recipient_id=realDonaldTrump" class="twitter-dm-button" data-screen-name="realDonaldTrump" data-show-count="false">Message @realDonaldTrump</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13785849)

Comment: True, but the page prompts you for information and generates the code. Seemed appropriate here